# xsl group by attribute multiple

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I'm transforming from an arbitrary XML format to HTML, I want to get continents name sorted by name with number of population (countries spans two continents).

I can only use (Constraint from teacher):

```
decimal-format,output, template, sort, variable, for-each, value-of, format
```

so I can't use the "xsl:for-each-group".

The following is the sample XML structure I'm working on:

```
<monde>
   <pays superficie="647500" code="AFG" capital="cty-Afghanistan-Kabul" continent="asia">
      <nom>Afghanistan</nom>
      <population>22664136</population>
      <frontieres>
         <frontiere codePays="TJ" longueur="76"/>
         <frontiere codePays="IR" longueur="936"/>
         <frontiere codePays="PK" longueur="2430"/>
         <frontiere codePays="TAD" longueur="1206"/>
         <frontiere codePays="TM" longueur="744"/>
         <frontiere codePays="UZB" longueur="137"/>
      </frontieres>
      <religions>
         <religion pourcentage="99">Muslim</religion>
      </religions>
      <villes>
         <ville>
            <nom>Kabul</nom>
            <population>892000</population>
         </ville>
      </villes>
   </pays>
   <pays superficie="28750" code="AL" capital="cty-cid-cia-Albania-Tirane"
         continent="europe"> ...
```

And some countries spans two continents  :

```
<pays superficie="780580" code="TR" ...
         continent="europe asia">
...
```

Example of output we needs

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>africa</td><td>667 586 143</td>
    <td>america</td><td>784 256 501</td>
    <td>asia</td><td>3 231 410 618</td>
    <td>australia</td><td>29 765 885</td>
    <td>europe</td><td>580 580 439</td>
 </tr>
</table
```

How can I solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Specifically, a complete XML that includes only the relevant elements in it. At this point your expected output shows no connection to the two snippets of XML you've provided. Also, it helps to show what you've tried and why it doesn't work. We also all understand what is allowed in XSLT 1.0 but why do you specify so few functions available to it? Is there some constraint that you haven't made clear?

Comment: Matthew Grenn i specify few functions because it's homework and we can use just this functions.

Comment: That's good to know. You should update the question then with that information so that everyone else that sees the question understands why you are limited. Also, while updating it, you should include more of the XML so that we can see how it actually relates to the expected output.

Comment: Mattew Green updating thanks

Comment: Are you sure that string handling functions are not allowed? If not I think it will be difficult to split the continent string into substrings. The only solution that I could currently think of would take advantage of the fact the continents are finite and well defined. Would you be willing to use that?

Comment: So you want to sum the population of each country and group it by continent? If that's true, then how do you handle countries that have more than one continent? Do you count the population twice?

Comment: Marcus I can't edit monde.xml so i need how to split continent ?

Comment: Matthew Green true, countries that have more than one continent i count population of twice .

Comment: Mattew Green : example of Turkey we count population in asia and europ;

Comment: Are node sets allowed? They are not explicitly declared in XSLT 2.0. Or are you actually also constrained to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: i need use XSLT 1.0 with few function.

Comment: From the allowed set of tags and the comments above I would deduce that we cannot use recursion (`apply-templates` and `call-template` forbidden), tokenization provided by a function (not in XSLT 1.0), or node sets  (not in XSLT 1.0). IMHO We would require either to solve the task. Thought experiment: the XSLT should also work for the simple case of one `<pays>` belonging to several continents being in the input file. This means we have to convert one input tag into several output tags by looking at the tokens in a string without tokenization. Sounds like magic!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how elegant this solution is but it will get you the output you are looking for and it only uses the elements that you are limited to.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="monde">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Africa</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(pays[contains(@continent,'africa')]/population)" />
        </td>
        <td>America</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(pays[contains(@continent,'america')]/population)" />
        </td>
        <td>Asia</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(pays[contains(@continent,'asia')]/population)" />
        </td>
        <td>Australia</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(pays[contains(@continent,'australia')]/population)" />
        </td>
        <td>Europe</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(pays[contains(@continent,'europe')]/population)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What this does is uses a [predicate](http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-14/s05/lecture-7/allslides.xhtml) to sum only the `population` of each country where the `continent` value contains the name of the continent you want to sum. So this would count the same population multiple times if it had more than one continent listed.

Comment: @Anouar: This solution corresponds to my remark _The only solution that I could currently think of would take advantage of the fact the continents are finite and well defined._ :-) I would really be interested if there is a generic solution to this, which could handle a new continent.